# /usr/bin/modulecmd: No such file or directory

Tags: mpi, slurm, sbatch, environment-modules

I'm using sbatch to submit my job.
Command line `mpirun --version` gives:

> Intel(R) MPI library for Linux* OS, Version 5.0 Build 20140507
>   Copyright (C) 2003-2014, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.

So I think I'm working with Intel mpi.
Following the [instructions: submitting an MPI job using Intel MPI](https://www.glue.umd.edu/hpcc/help/examples-submission.html), I write my script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntask=4
#SBATCH -t 00:10:00

. ~/.bash_profile

module load intel
mpirun mycc
```

mycc is the executable I get after compiling source files with mpicc.
Then I use command `sbatch -p partitionname -J myjob script.sh`, my job failed with exitcode 127:0. The slurm-jobid.out file says that(leave aside the set locale warning):

> /usr/share/Modules/init/sh: line 2: /usr/bin/modulecmd: No such file or directory
>   /tmp/slurmd/job252624/slurm_scirpt: line 10: mpirun: command not found

But I have checked and /usr/bin/modulecmd file does exist.
Any suggestion is aprreciated.

**Edit**
I also asked the question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1016692/usr-bin-modulecmd-no-such-file-or-directory).

I have removed the source statement and module load one.
 I tried to load the module on the log in node before submitting my job. But there is something wrong. It says that:

> moduleCmd_Lad.c(204): Error: 105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'intel'

I use `module avail` command to see what modules are available:

> ---------/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles-------------------
>
> dot         module-info    mpich2-x86_64 use.won
>
> module-cvs  modules        null
>
> ---------/etc/modulefiles---------------------------------
>
> compat-openmpi-psm-x86_64 compat-openmpi-x86_64

Forgive me for the messy formatting.

**Solved**

The problem is finally solved. My final script.sh is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
srun -p partitionname -n 4 -t 00:10:00 mycc
```

Then use command `sbatch -p partitionname -J myjob script.sh` to submit the job.

Comment: did you check it exist on the login node or on the compute nodes? I suspect the script is executed on the first node slurm allocated you, so if the `module` command is not installed there, you will get this error message...

Comment: Obviously not a Warwick student :^). You'll find more help on the Super User exchange as this is more sysadmin related than programming :).

Comment: @Gilles Can you be more specific? I mean, how can I check if the file exist on the login in node or on the compute nodes? I had thought that all files are stored on storage nodes.

Comment: @Samidamaru I'll cp my question there. :)

Comment: @Samindamaru the problem with Super User is that there is no slurm tag, so lots of users come here to ask, as there is more answers in Stack Overflow

Comment: Since `module` doesn't look like installed on the compute nodes, you should load the Intel module prior to submitting your job (and remove the corresponding command from your batch script) and then submitting the script with `sbatch -p partitionname -J myjob --export=ALL script.sh` to propagate the Intel runtime environment. Could you try that?

Comment: @Gilles I've edited the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Well, in essence, you don't have any Intel module... Then why did you expect the script you have to work in the first place? You really should contact your local system administration / support team.

Comment: @Gilles I think you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the /usr/bin/modulecmd does not exist in all the compute nodes. Make sure it exists in all the compute nodes and try again.

Also you shouldn't need to source the bash_profile if the /home is shared by all the nodes, as Slurm will export by default all the environment to the job.

Comment: Can you give some instructions on how to see if the file exist on compute nodes?

Comment: just using the same sbatch do an `ls /usr/bin/modulecmd`

Comment: The output message says: `ls: cannot access /usr/bin/modulecmd: No such file or directory.   /tmp/slurmd/jobid/slurm_script: /usr/bin/modulecmd: No such file or directory /tmp/slurmd/jobid/slurm_script: line 11: mpirun: command not found`.

Comment: So what can I do? I know that the the cluster seperate computing and storage, and three are computing nodes and storage devices and they are connected. The file system provide a global view for all nodes. That's what I'm taught about. But I do not quite understand and I think I must have misunderstood and got stuck somewhere.

Comment: There are no modules available in the compute nodes. What you can do is load the modules before submitting the job, and contact the cluster admins and ask them to install the modules on all the compute nodes.
If you load the modules on the login nodes, you should remove the `. ~/.bash_profile` and the `module load intel` commands